# Is there a simple way to remotely administer devices shipped to clients?

Tags: bash, ssh, nat

I plan on shipping small devices (like a MinnowBoard or CuBox) to some people. Is there some sort of software package that can "phone home" so that i have a way to administer it?

My current ideas are to use bash/netcat to provide a reverse shell, which will consistently try to connect to my server. But then I thought, what if more than one remote device tries to connect at the same time? Would it work correctly? Then ive been doing some research on AutoSSH.

Is there a relatively simple "NAT-proof" way to do this?

Comment: ntop's `n2n` comes to mind but it's not reliable, unfortunately.

Comment: `n2n` seems pretty cool! im gonna try it out...

Comment: i tried `n2n` and its pretty neat, ive done a little more research and i think im going to go with `openvpn`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright, I've tried n2n, openvpn, and tinc.

I feel that n2n definitely isn't as mature as the other two.
Openvpns hub-and-spoke topology is not ideal.

My favorite option was tinc.